# Error in implementing Android Websocket

Tags: android, cordova, websocket

I was trying to implement [this](https://github.com/anismiles/websocket-android-phonegap) websocket. But i was getting error in `GapWebSocket.java` that `The method execJS(String) is undefined for the type WebSocket`. I followed all the process like copying the java files to my src folder and copied websocket.js to js folder.

Please help me to find what process i miss.